# Tiled game, want to use as few external libraries as possible

Tags: objective-c, tiles

I am trying to make an iOS game. It's going to be 2D and tiled, but I am having some difficulty because really don't want to use external libraries if at all possible. I am using Tiled for designing my maps. Does anyone know of a tutorial or article that helps explain making a custom TMX loader?

This is supposed to be a learning experience that's why I don't want to use cocos2d.

Comment: its .tmx, its the file format that Tiled uses for saving 2D maps.

Comment: Even though you don't want to use it for your app, have you considered downloading cocos2d just to look at the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out for myself, TMX files are just XML and after some testing I was able to get one to load with NSXMLParser. The XML is described in detail here 
https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format